# My terminal is showing error for following code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

**ERROR**

*`Server started on port 4000 Database ErrorMongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 (node:1616) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\HARSH KUMAR SHARMA\Desktop\MEAN\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:845:32) at C:\Users\HARMA\Desktop\MEAN\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:345:10 at C:\Users\HARMA\Desktop\MEAN\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:5 at new Promise (<anonymous>) at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\HARSH KUMAR SHARMA\Desktop\MEAN\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:30:10) at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\HARMA\Desktop\MEAN\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1135:10) at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\HARMA\Desktop\MEAN\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:344:20) at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HARMA\Desktop\MEAN\app.js:10:10) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14) at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 (Use`node --trace-warnings ...`to show where the warning was created) (node:1616) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag*`--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
*(node:1616) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.*

**app.js** File

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require ('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport  = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./config/database');

// Connect to Database
mongoose.connect(config.database, {useNewUrlParser:true , useUnifiedTopology:true}); 

// On Connection
mongoose.connection.on('connected' , ()=>{
    console.log('Connected to DataBase' + config.database);
});

// On Error
mongoose.connection.on('error' , (err)=>{
    console.log('Database Error' + err);
});

const app = express();

const users = require('./routes/users');

// Port Number
const port = 4000 ;

// CORS Middleware
app.use(cors());

//Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname , 'public')));

//bodyParser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/users' , users);

//INDEX Route
app.get('/' , (req ,res) => {
    res.send('invalid Endpoint');
})

// Start Server  
app.listen(port , () => {
    console.log('Server started on port ' + port);
})
```

**database.js**  File

```
module.exports = {
    database: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/meanauth',
    secret : 'yoursecret'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your mongo is working or not and the node error you are getting of deprication is because you have not handled the error you can use try catch for this so that your error will be handled